# How can I make the main content width be based off the area remaining after a side bar is placed?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a side-bar menu that will widen and overlap the main content when hovered. I have it sort of working, but I can not get the main content to resize itself based on the area left on the screen, which is affecting how I try to center things. Everything seems off-kilter.

below is my code so far and a link to the Tailwind playground

https://play.tailwindcss.com/FxvoGuEzG6

```
    <div class="flex">
        <aside class="min-h-screen fixed bg-gray-700 rounded-r-lg">
            <div class="min-h-screen shadow-lg w-20 hover:w-56 duration-300 ease-in-out">
            </div>
        </aside>
    
        <div class="flex mx-auto w-[calc(100% - 80px)]">

            <div class="px-4">
                <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                    <div class="border-2 h-full w-full">
                        container 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="border-2 h-full grid grid-rows-2">
                        <div class="border">
                            grid col 2 container 1
                        </div>
                        <div class="border flex-grow">
                            grid col 2 container 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What is happening is the main content is being hidden behind the side bar (when it is not hovered if I make the screen size small enough). What I want to happen is have a side bar -> have the main content be based off of the area which is left on the screen so I can use flex to center and position things as I see fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'fixed' class set on the aside element makes it relative to the viewport and not your container. If you remove 'fixed' from the aside, it will now resize your content container properly. Now that you have that you can make the content the full width of the remaining space and add the 'justify-center' class to center your content horizontally.

**Try this**

```
<div class="flex">
    <aside class="min-h-screen fixed bg-gray-700 rounded-r-lg">
        <div class="min-h-screen shadow-lg w-20 hover:w-56 duration-300 ease-in-out">
        </div>
    </aside>

    <div class="flex w-full ml-20">

        <div class="px-4">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                <div class="border-2 h-full w-full">
                    container 1
                </div>
                <div class="border-2 h-full grid grid-rows-2">
                    <div class="border">
                        grid col 2 container 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="border flex-grow">
                        grid col 2 container 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that when you hover over the side-bar the main content does not auto resize but the side bar "covers the content". This is super close to what I was trying to do.

Comment: @DataD96 Your original code already does that, do you mean it should not initially cover the content? So the main content width should be based on the non-hovered size of the sidebar?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, yes I want the main content width to be based on the non-hovered size of the sidebar.

Comment: @DataD96 Just updated the code, does the solve the issue?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I was trying to do!